# getting vales from multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a name field having multiple delimiters like:

```
-----------------------------------
lastname
-----------------------------------
John
/ Sam Saw
- Dont Want To Share Name
/ Kim/ Ph  quu HO -Ceo / Mr ADi gilero
(Tor Tim)
(R)/ Nikki(R) / Phi / Hali
/ Isi Anna
\ Lorren Lush \ Ann
```

i want either the first value or the last value and remove all the unnecessary special characters.

My query:

```
SELECT  CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/', [last name], 0) = 0
            THEN [last name]
        ELSE LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('/', [last name], 0)-1)
        END AS Lastname
        ,CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/', [last name], 0) = 0
            THEN ''
        ELSE RIGHT([last name], CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([last name]), 0)-1)
        END AS Lastname 
        ,CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('\', [last name], 0) = 0
            THEN ''
        ELSE RIGHT([last name], CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([last name]), 0)-1)
        END AS Lastname 
        FROM aditya_dbprofile
```

However, my query is giving results in 3 columns .

Like:

```
-------------------------------------------------- 
lastname                   lastname       lastname
-------------------------------------------------- 
John   
                           sam saw
- Dont Want To Share Name 
                           Mr ADi gilero
(Tor Tim)
hal                        hali
                           isi anna
                                          ann
```

I want that all values should come under same column

Expected result:

```
------------------------
lastname
------------------------
John
Sam Saw
Dont Want To Share Name
Kim
Tor Tim
Hali
Isi Anna
Ann
```

Comment: case statements can have more than one condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use only one delimiter (`\`) and replace all other possible delimiters (`/`, `-`) with this one.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (LastName varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Data (LastName)
VALUES
   ('John'),
   ('/ Sam Saw'),
   ('- Dont Want To Share Name'),
   ('/ Kim/ Ph  quu HO -Ceo / Mr ADi gilero'),
   ('(Tor Tim)'),
   ('(R)/ Nikki(R) / Phi / Hali'),
   ('/ Isi Anna'),
   ('\ Lorren Lush \ Ann')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   REVERSE(LEFT(
      ReverseName, 
      CASE 
         WHEN CHARINDEX('\', ReverseName) = 0 THEN LEN(ReverseName) 
         ELSE CHARINDEX('\', ReverseName) - 1 
      END
   )) AS LastName
FROM (
   SELECT REVERSE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LastName, '/', '\'), '-', '\')) AS ReverseName 
   FROM Data
) t
```

Result:

```
-------------------------
LastName
-------------------------
John
 Sam Saw
 Dont Want To Share Name
 Mr ADi gilero
(Tor Tim)
 Hali
 Isi Anna
 Ann
```

Comment: why you have used here "reverse"   @Zhorov

Comment: @Adi, because you want the `last` word, so when the text is reversed, the last word is the word  before the separator or the whole name, if there is no separator. After that, you need an additional `REVERSE` to get the name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING` along with `PATINDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(PRE_LN,1,CASE WHEN G.POS!=0 THEN G.POS-1 
                          ELSE LEN(PRE_LN) END) AS LASTNAME
FROM (
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(LASTNAME,P1.POS, LEN(LASTNAME)-P1.POS+1) PRE_LN FROM TEST
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%',LASTNAME)))P1(POS)
    )SQ
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z ]%',PRE_LN)))G(POS)
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef87fba91482abd835dfbb3802bcaf3c)

This will give the output as follows.

[image]

*This will give you first value.Since you had mentioned first value or last value*