# Separate email addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column email in which some have multiple values like:

```
email
john@yy.com
marketing@baskin.com vividi@id.fj.com
```

I want to get only first email id. How to achieve this?

Expected result:

```
john@yy.com
marketing@baskin.com
```

Comment: Does `FIRST` work?

Comment: I guess you only want entries formated like xxx@xxx.xx and only the first one, seperated by space?

Comment: This is NO different from your previous question about [multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832426/getting-vales-from-multiple-delimiters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the first value, then use:

```
LEFT(emails, CHARINDEX(' ', emails + ' ') - 1)
```