# Remove unwanted characters from field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column and have phone numbers which have like comma , / which I want to remove and multiple phone from which I'm getting only first one.

```
Phone number
'+11223344588  / +612122121212 / +60123456789 / +6012345678
'+7733882223331 / +60123456789
'+1122334555566 / +6412345678
12123123123 (Mobile) / 6012345678
```

My query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', email) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(email, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', email)) ELSE email END
FROM aditya

My output:
'+11223344588 /
'+7733882223331 /
'+1122334555566 /
12123123123 (Mobile) /
```

I also want to remove "/" and '.

Comment: use [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) to remove the `/` and `'`. After that you can use [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862766/separate-email-address/) again to get the first phone number.

Comment: did you try REPLACE(fieldname, ',', '')

Comment: Are you just looking for `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(email, ' ', ''), '/', ''), '''', '')`?

Comment: The query can't give the shown result. You shouldn't get the `/` because there is a space before. In case you want to show `(Mobile)` also you have to change the separator from space to `/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862766/separate-email-addresses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have space (' ') always after the first phone number, you can use the below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3932b129f786ade1bb29c816c559172)

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ph,1) = 0 THEN REPLACE(ph,'''','')
    ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ph,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ph,1)),'''','')
END
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that the space is not really a space.  You can simplify your logic to:

```
LEFT(phone, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', phone + ' '))
```

However, you might find that `PATINDEX()` is a better choice:

```
LEFT(phone, 1, PATINDEX('[^+0-9]', phone + ' '))
```